# unwanted vertical space after \item

Tags: spacing, vertical-spacing

If I run the following code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\def\myproof#1{{\color{blue}\begin{proof}#1 \end{proof}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item 1
  \myproof{sdf}
  \item Thisis Thisis This is This is This is This is This is This is This is This.
  \myproof{sdf}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Then, I would get

[image]

which has a bad vertical spacing right above the second *Proof*.

I can solve this problem by adding `%` or `\leavevmode` right after `This.`

But is there any way I can prevent this in the first place by changing the definition of `\myproof`?

Comment: By inserting `\leavevmode` into the definition of `\myproof`? (side note `\textcolor` instead of `\color` might work better although I didn't try. different syntax however)

Comment: @user202729 Both of them do not work in this case...

Comment: You could place a `%` (comment) character right after `This.`.

Comment: `\unskip{\color{blue}...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `\par` in front of `\color{blue}`.

What happens in your example is that the space coming from the endline is followed by `{\color{blue}\begin{proof}...}` and the `\par` that's issued by `\begin{proof}` (actually by `\trivlist`, but it's not important) cannot remove it. So a line consisting of just one space is built.

This can be seen by the following example, where you see that masking the endline with `%` removes the spurious line.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\def\myproof#1{{\color{blue}\begin{proof}#1 \end{proof}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item 1
  \myproof{sdf}
  \item Thisis Thisis This is This is This is This is This is This is This is This.%
  \myproof{sdf}
  \item Thisis Thisis This is This is This is This is This is This is This is This.
  \myproof{sdf}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If we modify it as

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newcommand\myproof[1]{\par{\color{blue}\begin{proof}#1 \end{proof}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item 1
  \myproof{sdf}
  \item Thisis Thisis This is This is This is This is This is This is This is This.%
  \myproof{sdf}
  \item Thisis Thisis This is This is This is This is This is This is This is This.
  \myproof{sdf}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

you can see that the `%` is no longer necessary.

[image]

My preferred way would be

```
\newenvironment{blueproof}{\par\color{blue}\proof}{\endproof}
```

using

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item 1
  \begin{blueproof}
  sdf
  \end{blueproof}
  \item Thisis Thisis This is This is This is This is This is This is This is This.
  \begin{blueproof}
  sdf
  \end{blueproof}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect! thanks!

Comment: @user182849 I'd much prefer the environment form I added.

Comment: May I ask you why?

Comment: @user182849 Cleaner to input if the proof is long.